# Keyboard Shortcuts not working in Jupyter Notebook v 7.0.6--but will work in nbClassic & JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use Jupyter notebook heavily and very recently the keyboard shortcuts stopped working. 'A' to insert above, 'B' to insert below, 'D,D' to delete, enter to edit highlighted cell-- they all stopped working. Even the un-delete doesn't work. I had to open history.sqlite to retrieve a very important cell I accidently deleted.

Also to be clear: I can still shift + enter/ctrl + enter to run the cell. THOSE shortcuts work. When I am editing the cell contents, I can still use copy/paste/and other 'general' keyboard shortcuts. I am guessing that when I 'escape' from the cell, that's when the keys get 'ignored.'

How it happened: I was writing code and they randomly stopped working! In the middle of typing in Jupyter and it just... stopped.

What I've done: They work in Jupyter nbClassic and JupyterLab! I even logged into incognito mode to make sure all extensions were turned off (I read that some extensions will intercept keystrokes) and it still doesn't work.

Interestingly enough I just tried using Edge (I use Chrome for notebooks + usual browsing). Same results! It has to be a setting right? I've reset all keyboard shortcuts to default. It effects all notebooks!

Also I'm using a Windows computer, windows 11.

I've reinstalled Chrome, Jupyter, Anaconda (I use Anaconda typically), and nothing has worked! It's frustrating because I really use keyboard shortcuts in all of my day-to-day applications.

This appears to only affect Jupyter 7 on my machine. Any advice?

Comment: You may want to add your detailed findings [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/shortcuts-that-were-present-in-notebook-6-xx-not-available-with-7-07/23846?u=fomightez)? I know the title of that post there makes it seem different; however, maybe it is the same thing? Hopefully, we can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: It looks to be SLIGHTLY different. I have been using Jupyter 7 for about a month. This post claims that they downloaded Jupyter 7 and it instantly was broken. It COULD be the same? Maybe an update to one of the dependencies that was downloaded with it broke it? there's a suggestion to downgrade to a previous version of JLab that I already have

Comment: Hello, you came to my post on the Jupyter forum. In my case, creating a new environment and installing notebook again installed jupyterlab==4.0.12 rather than jupyterlab==4.1.0 previously. This version change was a suggested solution on the post and even if I don't know if that's specifically this change that solved my problem, shortcuts now seem to work.

Comment: I don't think that the issue lies in JupyterLab 4.1.0. I was using 4.0.11 when I ran into the issues. Plus I've been using Jupyter Notebook 7 for about a month ish when I ran into the issues. I did downgrade, however to JLab 4.0.8 and now it works! I wonder if there was some dependency that downgrading helps fix this issue.

Comment: I had the same issue with 7.0.7. In the shortcut list (ctrl+shift+h) the shortcuts "a", "b", "dd" among others were not listed anymore. Just reinstalled 7.0.8, shortcuts came back and work again and do appear in the shortcut list. So I thing that was an issue with 7.0.7 ?

Comment: I am having this same issue starting recently but in vscode. arrow keys work but j, k, dd all fail to work

Comment: @Zak fyi *vscode* != *jupyter notebook* (they both run notebooks but they are not the same application). Any similarity between the way they handle shortcuts is (probably) intentional but not necessary or guaranteed. And of course, any bugs they have are their own bugs.

Comment: I have the same issue on Mac. Sometimes when I start `jupyter notebook` from the command line I have the same problem described in the original post and sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

pip install notebook==7.0.8

I got the same issue in 7.0.7, some shortcuts were not working (A, B, DD). Then upgrade to latest version (7.1.2) but still did not fix it. Then **downgraded to 7.0.8** and all shortcuts are working again!