Jupyter Notebook shortcut keys are not working anymore
I am running Python 3.11.9 (conda version 24.11.0) on macOS Sonoma 14.7.1. It seems that I cannot use the Jupyter Notebook (ipython version 8.29.0; jupyter notebook version 7.0.6) shortcut keys anymore: I cannot insert a new cell above (A) or below (B) or delete it (D) etc. Nothing works. There are suggestions to use JupyteLab, which seems to work, but that's really not the answer to the question: How can this issue be fixed? Can I downgrade? And if so, what is the recommended version?
Thanks!

A similar question (different versions of Jupyter) was resolved by downgrading to a prior release.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77970655/keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-in-jupyter-notebook-v-7-0-6-but-will-work-in-nbc Probably the source of your current potential workaround

Try pip install --force-reinstall "notebook<7" There's a big difference in how things work between Notebook 6 vs 7.

Thanks JonSG! pip install or conda install or it does not really matter?

pip vs conda matters. If you are using Anaconda/conda then that is your primary package manager and should always be used, except in the cases you cannot. This will give you much more robust and portable environments in the long run.

Thanks Wayne. This is why I did conda install "notebook<7" --force-reinstall
